# Причастия  от глагола блистать

Tags: словообразование, причастия

Как образовать страдательное причастие прошедшего времени от глагола БЛИСТАТЬ? Ведь он переходный и несовершенного вида.

Comment: *Кстати, Юлия Демичева, совет. Не занимайтесь пока "награждением" участников. Вы тратите га это свои баллы репутации, которых у вас и так очень мало. Вполне достаточно поставить лайк или дислайк соответственно понравившемуся или не понравившемуся ответу.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть единичный случай образования такого слова поэтом: блистанный (видимо, там небо озарялось блеском других сущностей).
http://www.rospisatel.ru/rebrov.htm
Ну и в шутку можно вывести вариант совершенного вида "блистанутый" :)

Answer (score 1):

Страдательные причастия от глаголов несовершенного вида регулярно не образуются. В этом, собственно, и есть единственный смысл введения в модели русской грамматики категории переходности. Есть единичные и небезусловные исключения (типа "руководимый"), но "блистать"-"блистанный" к ним не относится. Тут дело в том, что само понятие, выражаемое такой гипотетической формой, отсутствует.

Что там поэт намудрил - это отдельный разговор. Без контекста и непонятно. 
Мдя... Там и по контексту непонятно, что имелось в виду...

А почему не "блистотый"?

Comment: (почему не "блистотый")

Близкий по форме пример реально возможных, практических словобразований (без поэтических вольностей):

хлестать - хлёстанный (тот, кого хлестали не раз)
хлестнуть - хлёстнутый (кого хлестнули один раз)
хлестануть - хлестанутый (простор.; кого разок хлестнули хорошенько)

Размолоть - вот тогда "размолотый".

Answer (score 1):

А с чего вы взяли, что он переходный? Кого или что вы собирались блистать?
Блистать `Толковый словарь Ефремовой`
несов. неперех.

Comment: Вот теперь все стало на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

а блисталый не подходит Вам?)